# How to use SortedList in Java

Tags: sortedlist, sortedset

I have this kind of list in C#

```
public SortedList<int, SortedList<int, Match>> TournamentRoundMatches { get; private set; }
```

How can I write it in Java ?

I try using SortedSet but it doesnt work...

```
SortedSet<Integer, SortedSet<Integer, Match>> TournamentRoundMatches = new SortedSet<Integer, SortedSet<Integer, Match>>(){}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name `SortedList` is actually misleading as it is not a sorted list, but actually a sorted dictionary (sorted by its keys). The best comparable Java equivalent for a `SortedList` is a `TreeMap`:

```
TreeMap<Integer, TreeMap<Integer, Match>> TournamentRoundMatches = new TreeMap<Integer, TreeMap<Integer, Match>>(){}
```